# Function typing issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I ran into a problem in function typing, please tell me what I did wrong.
Commented places in the last block of code tell me about typing errors.
Functions moved to a separate file for reuse

**types**

```
export interface ITable {
  rows: IRow[];
  setRows: () => void;
}

export interface IRow {
  id: number;
  rowName: string;
  salary: number;
}
```

**state component**

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState<IRow[]>([]);
```

**functions**

```
const deepSearchByKey = (object, originalKey: string, matches = []) => {    // <--here
    if (object != null) {
        if (Array.isArray(object)) {
            for (let arrayItem of object) {
                deepSearchByKey(arrayItem, originalKey, matches);
            }
        } else if (typeof object == "object") {
            for (let key of Object.keys(object)) {
                if (key === originalKey) {
                    matches.push(object);                                  //<-- here
                } else {
                    deepSearchByKey(object[key], originalKey, matches);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
};
export const gettingData = async (rows: IRow[], setRows: () => void) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}${gettingDataUrl}`);
    let result = deepSearchByKey(response, "rowName");
    if (rows.length === 0) {
        setRows((prevState) => [...prevState, ...result]);                 //<-- and here
    }
};
```

Comment: start with adding explicit types everywhere

Comment: @njzk2 ``matches = []`` 
added as empty array, no type specified
Could you suggest what needs to be changed and added? I've been sitting on this for a really long time

Comment: `matches = []` infers `matches` as `never[]`. It is equivalent to `matches: never[] = []`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the type of `matches`: it is inferred from `[]` into being a `never[]`

If you are explicit with your types, it should be fine. The function can be declared as:

```
const deepSearchByKey = (object:any, originalKey: string, matches:any[] = []) => {
```

Comment: But specifying any is bad practice. This is exactly what I had, but I decided to rewrite it to make it right

Comment: You are right about the ``object`` count, because when iterating over the keys, completely different data types get there. But for ``matches``, ``IRow[]`` is better.
How do you think how to type the second function? Her last part

Comment: not specifying anything is implicitly specifying `any`. `object` is, in fact, `any`, at this point. `matches` is `IRow[]`, but then you can't `push` `any` in it. You need to cast this `object` at some point.

Comment: I don't know what is the signature of `setRows`